# PHP upload_max_filesize

Tags: file, upload, filesize, php

How can you set `upload_max_filesize` **to no limit?**

Could you say `upload_max_filesize = -1` **(As you can with other things)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of, and why would you? Your server's memory will thank you for not doing that. And why allow a user to upload a "file" that will fill your server.

Comment: furthermore IE6 will crap out long before a file that big ever gets sent. most users will abort. there must be some practical limit you can accept, use that.

Comment: "why allow a user to upload a "file" that will fill your server." I'm not, its just a question

Comment: Well I answered it, there is no way I know of where you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Its based on the maximum value of the POST you can get.

[post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Might also need to set the memory limit.

If its too large, it can be abused.